# Automatic Credit Card payment authorization

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, payment-processing

Some agency of webhosting, allow **automatic** credit card payment every year without entering each time the credit card number and CCV code.

How could I do this ( asking user's permission of course ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several companies that can provide you with recurring billing capabilities, which will not only take the development workload off your plate, but handle the PCI requirements. Take a look at Recurly, Chargify, Cheddargetter, or Spreedly. Based on your needs, one of these companies should be able to help you out.

Disclaimer: I work for Recurly. I'd be happy to answer any of your questions or point you to the right processor for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Cybersource](http://www.cybersource.com/) for ours, although I expect there are a variety of others that work in similar ways.

They have an authorization API (via a Web Service) where we get a request token (so we don't have to store CC info, etc.) and can run our payments against their web service during our billing cycle (and can see if a CC is declined).  They also have excellent reporting, etc.

In our case, we do automated processing on a monthly basis automatically.  Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.Net has their [Automatic Recurring Billing API](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/automatedrecurringbilling/) which allows you to schedule regular automated payments on a user's credit card. This sounds like a perfect example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Plimus** has powerful API which allows you to authorize a card, set up recurring billing, and even add or subtract from the next billing amount (make corrections) - great for pay-per-usage stuff.